# iText java: streaming of a concatenated pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext

So I am generating a 500+ page document by concatenating 250 individual pdfs of 2 pages each. Each pdf is a form which has fields that data is placed into. 
I would like to stream content to the browser two pages at a time.

Currently I am waiting for the entire document to be generated before sending anything to the browser and this is causing some timeout problems.

This is a simplified form of what I am doing:

```
PdfCopyFields pdfCopier = new PdfCopyFields(outputStream);
for(Receipt receipt: receipts) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    generator.generateSaleDocument(receipt.getId(), baos);
    pdfCopier.addDocument(new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray()));
}
pdfCopier.close();
outputStream.flush();
```

How do I stream these PDFs instead of sending them as one big bunch?

Comment: While pdf readers may optimize their data retrieval by using range requests, the pdf usually has to already exist fully beforehand and the server must allow for range requests. Thus, there is no streaming of pdf as you would like to see. You might want to render images and serve them one after the other, though.

Comment: Correct. "Fast Web View" or "Linearized PDF" isn't supported by iText, and even if it was, it would be in a post-processing operations as you need to have the full PDF before you can "linearize" it.